# How to prevent soft keyboard from closing when DONE is pressed

Tags: android, ios, flash, air

I open keyboard as described here: http://recycledinformation.blogspot.com/2011/10/custom-text-entry-on-ios.html (Hidden flash.display.TextField). Everything works as expected.

Now I want to prevent soft keyboard from closing when user clicks on "DONE" button.

If there any way to do it in Action Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextField multiline must be set to true.